# ModRewrite statement redirect to user profile

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to write simple Apache mod_rewrite statement, which redirect user urls to a script:

```
**http://mydomain.com/username -> http://mydomain.com/user.py?uname=username**
mydomain.com/username -> http://mydomain.com/user.py?uname
mydomain.com/username -> http://mydomain.com/user.py?uname
```

The following lines don't work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{5,}$  /user.py?username=$1 [L]
```

Looking forward for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /user.py?uname=$1 [L]
```

This makes it so when someone requests `http://mydomain.com/username`, they will get served the content at `http://mydomain.com/user.py?uname=username`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm.
Just replaced ^([^/]+)$  for ^[a-z\d.]{5,}$ for better user validation